# Can I set a custom link on a custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am creating custom post types in WordPress using the "Types" plugin. Those post types are not supposed to have a post page associated with them that the user would navigate to by default when clicking a particular post link. They are supposed to be merely titles that I am displaying in a grid and that should link out to separate sites. Every post title has an individual link associated with it. I am styling those post titles using the "Grid Element" creator of the "Visual Composer" plugin, so I can set which attributes of the post I want to display (in my case only the title).

When I am creating the post type, I am adding a custom field for the link url that I can then set when I create the individual post. However, I am not seeing an option to set that custom link to be the link for the post itself. I can add the link as a separate UI element of the post but I want the post title itself to be the link. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Very possible, but you will have to do some coding of your own, rather than relying on visual composer. Within the template you are using, in the loop that pulls the posts, you need to grab the meta data from that field for the current post:

```
<?php
// loop stuff here...
$link = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), your-key-here, true);
echo '<p><a href="'.$link.'">'.the_title().'</a></p>';
// other loop stuff...
?>
```

In the above, your-key-here refers to the name of the custom field you've set up for the link that gets set by the post author. The above also assumes you know enough about WordPress to know where you need to edit this code in, in the template. The code does not check for empty values and handle with a fallback, so yes, this code can be improved upon, but it sill do what you've asked in the question.

EDIT: A link for reference regarding pulling meta data/custom fields data; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/